# Reading .csv data with inconsistent pattern

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-csv, csv-parser

I have a very huge CSV file. I want to read it through Pyspark but I am not able to read it properly.

Sample csv as

```
"keyvalue","rto","state","maker_model","veh_type","veh_class"
"hnjsnjncjssssmj", "OD", "ODISHA", "BAJAJ AUTO", "Private Vehicle", "Car"
"hnjsnjncjssssjj", "OD", "ODISHA", "BAJAJ AUTO
", "Private Vehicle", "Car"
"hnjsnjncjssssmm", "GO", "GOA", "TATA MOTORS", "Private Vehicle", "Bus"
```

I want to read it as like this

```
+---------------+-----+---------+--------------+------------------+---------+
|       keyvalue|  rto|    state|   maker_model|          veh_type|veh_class|
+---------------+-----+---------+--------------+------------------+---------+
|hnjsnjncjssssmj| "OD"| "ODISHA"|  "BAJAJ AUTO"| "Private Vehicle"|    "Car"|
|hnjsnjncjssssjj| "OD"| "ODISHA"|  "BAJAJ AUTO"| "Private Vehicle"|    "Car"|
|hnjsnjncjssssmm| "GO"|    "GOA"| "TATA MOTORS"| "Private Vehicle"|    "Bus"|
```

but my pyspark is unable to recognise 2nd row properly and it's breaking it like

```
+--------------------+------+---------+--------------+------------------+---------+
|            keyvalue|   rto|    state|   maker_model|          veh_type|veh_class|
+--------------------+------+---------+--------------+------------------+---------+
|     hnjsnjncjssssmj|  "OD"| "ODISHA"|  "BAJAJ AUTO"| "Private Vehicle"|    "Car"|
|     hnjsnjncjssssjj|  "OD"| "ODISHA"|   "BAJAJ AUTO|              null|     null|
|", "Private Vehicle"| "Car"|     null|          null|              null|     null|
|     hnjsnjncjssssmm|  "GO"|    "GOA"| "TATA MOTORS"| "Private Vehicle"|    "Bus"|
+--------------------+------+---------+--------------+------------------+---------+
```

I have tried various configurations in read csv function of spark but as of now nothing is working. Please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Spark provides some useful options for reading the csv files. In your case we can use

```
df = (
    spark.read
    .option('header', True)
    .option('multiline', True)
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", True)
    .csv('data.csv')
)
```

---

```
df.show()

+---------------+---+------+------------+---------------+---------+
|       keyvalue|rto| state| maker_model|       veh_type|veh_class|
+---------------+---+------+------------+---------------+---------+
|hnjsnjncjssssmj| OD|ODISHA|  BAJAJ AUTO|Private Vehicle|      Car|
|hnjsnjncjssssjj| OD|ODISHA|BAJAJ AUTO\n|Private Vehicle|      Car|
|hnjsnjncjssssmm| GO|   GOA| TATA MOTORS|Private Vehicle|      Bus|
+---------------+---+------+------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: This worked thank you, if i want to remove \n from my df, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too large you could use regex to fix the broken lines and then read the fixed file in with spark.

```py
import re

# matches lines where the last character is not a "
pattern = r'(?<=[^\"])\n'

with open('data.csv', 'r') as data_file:
    content = data_file.read()
    fixed = re.sub(pattern, '', content)

    with open('fixed.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write(fixed)
```